# How do i use local files in react app without importing them

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im building a blog application and i just realized i can not use local file paths in react, and since the response of my REST api is a unique path for every image, i cant use it in react.

Is there a way of going around this without importing every single image?

This is what i am currently doing:

```
const imgSrc = this.state.post.img_path

const styles = {
    background: 'url('+imgSrc+')'
}
```

and then i apply the styles to the element.

I do this cause soon im going to update it and make it so i will upload 3 different images for different screen sizes.

Comment: Is your image path relative? Do you store them in your `public` folder?

Comment: Actually i dont store them in my public folder, i store them outside of the react folder. And the path is not relative, I use realpath in php to get the actual path of the file cause when i upload the website on a host, i want the paths to be usable.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Instead of storing my images outside of the public folder, i changed the upload location to store the images in the public/images folder. Thankfully i only had a few images so it wasnt that bad.

Then i set the url to be:

```
"https://localhost:3007/images/" + image name gotten from REST api response
```

and now it works.

Comment: You could set it to "/images/namehere" aswell. Since the public folder is the root.